# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, logarithms, contour-integration

How would I go about evaluating this integral?
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx.$$
What I've tried so far: I tried a semicircular integral in the positive imaginary part of the complex plane, excluding the negative real axis, but had trouble calculating the residue at $z=i$ (perhaps there is a way of doing this that I don't know of). After that didn't work, I tried a rectangular box integral from $\epsilon$ to $R$, from $R$ to $R+i/2$, from $R+i/2$ to $-S+i/2$, from $-S+i/2$ to $-S+i\epsilon$, from $-S+i\epsilon$ to $-\epsilon+i\epsilon$ and finally a semicircle around the origin, radius $\epsilon$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Numerically it seems to be $\pi \ln 2$. Now, the contour method is rather usual, you should get $\pi \mathrm{Res}_i(f)$, but you'll have a problem with residue at $i$.

Comment: @arbautjc Yes, we can find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177160/integral-int-infty-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx some methods (but not complex, using contour integration).

Comment: Oh, my. I have found $\int_0^{\pi/2} \log{(1+\tan^2 x)}\mathrm{d}x$, but I just forgot that $1+\tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$. Thanks!

Comment: Note that, you have two branch points.

Comment: But you integrate with a half disc covering the upper half-plane. When it works, anyway.

Comment: this is relevant http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189590/can-int-0-pi-2-ln-sinx-dx-be-evaluated-with-complex-integral

Comment: I think the $\infty$ must be +$\infty$ ..

Comment: Integrate $f(z) = \frac{\ln(z+i)}{z^{2}+1}$ around a large closed half-circle in the upper half plane.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340534/integrate-lnx21-x21?lq=1 and here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189590/can-int-0-pi-2-ln-sinx-dx-be-evaluated-with-complex-integral?lq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hints**
As RandomVariable suggested, use $\log(x^2+1)=\log(x+i)+\log(x-i)$, choosing the branches of the logarithm carefully. It's generally best to isolate unpleasant singular things.

Then write $$\int_0^\infty=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ and make use of the above splitting to integrate the two parts on different contours, each time avoiding enclosing the singularity of the logarithm. The part on the semicircle vanishes.

---

**Answer**
The UHP pole gives $\log(i+i)/2i\times2\pi i$. The LHP pole gives $\log(-i-i)/(-2i)\times-2\pi i$. Summing and halving gives the answer $$\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\log(2i)+\log(-2i)\right)$$ so all that remains is choosing the right logarithm. This is easy enough, actually, and the answer is what you expect: $$\pi\ln 2$$

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but you're still wrong! It is $\pi \ln 2$ just like I said, and just like I verified by checking it in Mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica gives: Integrate[Log[x^2 + 1]/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, Infinity}] = \[Pi] Log[2]

Comment: -2 Integrate[Log[Cos[t]], {t, 0, Pi/2}] = \[Pi] Log[2] also holds.

Comment: If I may ask, what attracted the downvote, whoever did so? If this answer is wrong somehow I and the OP would probably like to know! If you just prefer the other answer, upvote that, don't downvote me...

Comment: BTW I did not give you the downvote.

Comment: @RonGordon (a) To capture the LHP pole, you encircle it with a contour in a *positive* orientation, and hence you accumulate $\frac{1}{2}\times\boxed{-}2\pi i$ times this contribution.
(b) Each $\log$ should be of variables whose arguments range in $(-\pi,\pi)$ on the real line. This is because the imaginary parts of the $\log$ must cancel from $x=+\infty$ down to $x=-\infty$.

Comment: (a) I do not understand - why $-i 2 \pi$ if the contour is of a positive orientation?  (b) *The imaginary parts of the log must cancel...* - I do not have any idea of what this means.  (I am not trying to make trouble - it's just that I had already tried this way without success before I used the contour in my answer below.)

Comment: (a) Apologies, meant "negative". This is a standard fact. Try computing $\oint_C \mathrm dz/z$ directly for $C$ clockwise and anticlockwise. (b) You need $\log(x+i) + \log(x-i) = \log(1+x^2)$ to hold. Evaluate at zero. With your choice of the logarithm's branch, you find $\log(i) + \log(-i) = i\pi/2+3i\pi/2 = 2i\pi \neq 0 = \log(1+0^2)$, so you chose a discontinuous logarithm. [You also missed out an $i$ in your expression for the imaginary part of the logarithm.]

Comment: OK, I am with you.  Sorry for grilling you.

Answer (score 30):

Use $x\to \tan\theta$ and $dx=\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$.
The integral becomes $$\int_0^{\pi/2} 2\ln (\sec \theta) d\theta$$

Which is $$-2\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln (\cos\theta) d\theta$$
And can be solved.

> Let $$I= \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left( \sin \theta \right) \cdot d\theta$$
> $$I= \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left( \cos \theta \right) \cdot d\theta$$
> Adding both.
> $$2I=\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left( \sin \theta \times \cos \theta\right) \cdot 
> d\theta$$
> $$2I= \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left(2 \sin \theta\times \cos \theta \right) -\ln2 \cdot d\theta$$
> $$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin{2\theta})-\ln2 \cdot d\theta$$
> $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin{2\theta})\cdot d\theta=I$$
> So,
> $$I=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln2\cdot d\theta$$
> $$I=-\dfrac{\pi\ln2}2$$

And your integral comes out to be

### $${\pi \ln2}$$

Comment: This is tagged as complex analysis, and I believe OP wants to use contour integration. (Nice approach,though, so +1).

Comment: It is not a perception. This is based on the tags (which now include contour-integration tag) and the question description.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: The answer has been edited but is still wrong; I'd beware of calling it a "nice approach" since it's apparently very easy to make errors! P:

Comment: There's a mistake but I think it is a rather minor one and the approach indeed is nice:$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin 2\theta\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\pi\log\sin u\,du=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin u\,du\implies$$in the second line from the bottom in the blue zone of the answer it must be $$I=-\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\log 2\,d\theta\ldots$$

Comment: @Sharkos: It is a nice (and rather clever) approach. It is easy to make mistakes irrespective of the approach one takes! And as DonAntonio pointed out, they are minor in this case.

Comment: There was a P: at the end of my message for a reason. It's a fun way to do it, I agree. The more mechanical way I offer is more straightforward to do off the bat, though, and therefore less error-prone.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanx for pointing out.

Comment: My pleasure indeed, and of course +1 (I can't understand how come I didn't upvote this before...)

Answer (score 26):

Maybe this is going to seem a lot more involved than it needs to be, but it is likely that complex methods are not the best way to attack an integral like this.  Nonetheless, it is possible.

We consider the integral in the complex plane

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2}$$

where $C$ is some contour to be determined.  Our first instinct is to make $C$ a simple semicircle in the upper half plane.  The problem is that the branch point singularity at $z=i$ is extremely problematic, as it coincides with an ostensible pole.  Nonetheless, the corresponding integral over the real line is finite (and twice the originally specified integral), so there must be a way to treat this.

The way to go with branch points like this is to avoid them.  We thus have to draw $C$ so as to do that, and then use Cauchy's theorem to state that the above complex integral about $C$ is zero.  Such a contour $C$ is illustrated below.

[image: imagbranch]

The contour integral is then taken along six different segments.  I will state without proof that the integral about the two outer arcs vanishes as the radius of those arcs $R \to \infty$.  We are then left with four integrals:

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} + \left [\int_{C_-}+\int_{C_+}+\int_{C_{\epsilon}} \right ] dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} = 0$$

$C_-$ is the segment to the right of the imaginary axis, down from the arc to the branch point, $C_+$ is the segment to the left of the imaginary axis, up from the branch point to the arc, and $C_{\epsilon}$ is the circle about the branch point of radius $\epsilon$.

It is crucial that we get the arguments of the log correct along each path.  I note that the segment $C_-$ is "below" the imaginary axis and I assign the phase of this segment to be $2 \pi$, while I assign the phase of the segment $C_+$ to be $0$.

For the segment $C_-$, set $z=i(1+y e^{i 2 \pi})$:

$$\int_{C_-} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} = i\int_R^{\epsilon} dy \frac{\log{[-y (2+y)]}+ i 2 \pi}{-y (2+y)} $$

For the segment $C_+$, set $z=i(1+y)$:

$$\int_{C_-} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} = i\int_{\epsilon}^R dy \frac{\log{[-y (2+y)]}}{-y (2+y)} $$

I note that the sum of the integrals along $C_-$ and $C_+$ is

$$-2 \pi \int_{\epsilon}^R \frac{dy}{y (2+y)} = -\pi \left [ \log{R} - \log{(2 + R)} - \log{\epsilon} + \log{(2 + \epsilon)}\right]$$

For the segment $C_{\epsilon}$, set $z=i (1+\epsilon e^{-i \phi})$.  The integral along this segment is

$$\begin{align}\int_{C_{\epsilon}} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} &= \epsilon \int_{-2 \pi}^0 d\phi e^{-i \phi} \frac{\log{\left [ -2 \epsilon e^{-i \phi} \right]}}{-2 \epsilon e^{-i \phi}}\end{align}$$

Here we use $\log{(-1)}=-i \pi$ and the above integral becomes

$$\begin{align}\int_{C_{\epsilon}} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} &= -\frac12 (-i \pi)(2 \pi) - \frac12 \log{2} (2 \pi) - \frac12 \log{\epsilon} (2 \pi) -\frac12 (-i) \frac12 (0-4 \pi^2) \\ &= -\pi \log{2} - \pi \log{\epsilon} \end{align}$$

Adding the above integrals, we have

$$\begin{align}\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} -\pi \log{R} + \pi \log{(2 + R)} + \pi \log{\epsilon} - \pi \log{(2 + \epsilon)} -\pi \log{2} - \pi \log{\epsilon} &= 0\\ \implies \int_{-R}^R dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} -\pi \log{R} + \pi \log{(2 + R)} - \pi \log{(2 + \epsilon)} -\pi \log{2} &=0\end{align}$$

Now we take the limit as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ and we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} -2 \pi \log{2} = 0$$

Therefore

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} = \pi \log{2}$$

Comment: @EricNaslund: many thanks.

Comment: (+1) Finally solution with contuor integration, like OP wanted (I suppose).

Comment: @Ron You directed me to your post, so I hope you're willing to answer some of my questions.  I don't think the branch of $\log(1+z^{2})$ you used coincides with that cut. I'm pretty sure that cut is the result of using the principal branch of $\log(1+z^{2})$.   And when I parametrized the contour around the branch point at $z=i$, I assumed I could replace $(i+\epsilon  e^{it})^{2}$ with $-1 + 2i\epsilon e^{it}$ since we're only interested in small values of $\epsilon$. You seem to have done something similar but without stating what you did. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The branch of the log doesn't coincide with what cut?  And I did exactly what you said, see the integral about $C_{\epsilon}$.  It is certainly there - we are just making sure we are picking up the contribution from the branch point.

Comment: I assume we want the branch cuts on the imaginary axis from $i$ to $i \infty$ and from $-i$ to $-i \infty$.  Along those cuts $1+z^{2}$ is negative and real. So those cuts come about by choosing the principal branch of $\log(1+z^{2})$.  So the argument of $\ln(1+z^{2})$ just to the right of the cut on $[i, i \infty)$ is $\pi$, while just to the left of the cut the argument is $- \pi$.

Comment: That is correct, but it makes no difference.  In general, once you get comfortable with this, you know to replace the log with a jump of $i 2 \pi$.

Comment: I know.  But it could matter in other situations using other functions. And finally how can we be certain that we will still pick up the contribution from the branch point after making that simplification?

Comment: I agree that I should have gotten the phase right, and really, great catch.  It matters when we are dealing with higher powers of log.  For integrals linear in log, only the phase difference matters, so the mistake escaped my scrutiny.

Comment: @RonGordon How does the integral over the two outer arcs vanish?  I don't think this is very straightforward.

Comment: @user108149: depends on what you mean by straightforward.  I think it is; just sub $z=R e^{i \theta}$ and note that the integral over each arc is bounded by $$\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\log{R}}{R}$$ which certainly goes to zero.  See for yourself.

Comment: @RonGordon How is it bounded by that term?  If anything, I'd say that it's bounded by $\frac{\log(R^2+1)}{R^2-1}$, and I'm not really sure how to deal with that logarithm.

Comment: I learned more about complex analysis from Ron Gordon than from my C.A. book

Comment: This might be a silly question, but how do you know that the principal branch cut is $(i,i\infty)\cup (-i,-i\infty)$? Or did you pick it out of convenience? Could we instead, choose a branch cut on $(-i,i)$?

Comment: @RonGordon Can you explain how you arrived at the substitutions? For example, why do we substitute $z=i(1+\epsilon e^{-i\phi})$ for the circular arc?

Comment: @FrankW.: the substitutions are parametrizations of the contour pieces.  The one you pointed out is how we parametrize a circular arc of radius $\epsilon$ centered on the point $z=i$.

Comment: @RonGordon Do you have any books or sources that go over all the different "types" of poles in complex analysis? I remember seeing something about a pole at infinity and was really confused by that. I'm sure you get this question a lot so sorry if somebody has already asked this.

Comment: There is a book called "The Cauchy Method of Residues."  It is expensive but it is pretty good at treating different types of singularities in the complex plane.

Answer (score 23):

One way to solve this problem is to use parametric integrals. Let
$$ I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(\alpha x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
I'(\alpha)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(\alpha x^2+1)(x^2+1)}dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\frac{1}{\alpha x^2+1}+\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)dx\\
&=&-\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}-1}{\sqrt{\alpha}(\alpha-1)}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}+1}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus
$$ I(\alpha)=\pi\ln(\sqrt{\alpha}+1)+C. $$
But $I(0)=0$ implies $C=0$. So $I(1)=\pi\ln 2$.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could address the following doubts. Thanks. (1) How do you relate your $\,I(\alpha)\,$ with the original integral? That has logarithm in the numerator, yours doesn't ; (2) you're apparently differentiating under the integral sign, but if so how do get what you write in $\,I'(\alpha)\,$?

Comment: There should be a log applied to the numerator, then it works fine.

Comment: It looks like a neat approach, but something is wrong. Want to fix it?

Comment: @nbubis, tell me which place is wrong so that I can fix.

Comment: @DonAntonio, for this type of integrals which the numerators have $\ln(x+1),\ln(x^2+1)$ or $e^{x}$, the general idea is to change the numerators as $\ln(\alpha x+1),\ln(\alpha x^2+1)$ or $e^{\alpha x}$ and then to differentiate and integrate. Then the key is that if $\alpha=0$, the integrals become 0.

Comment: Indeed there is something strange. For $\alpha = 0$, it's true that $I(0)$ is well defined, but $I'(0)$ is not. The formula you obtained by derivation was used to express $I(\alpha)$ and you used this formula (which doesn't necessarily holds for $\alpha = 0$) to make $\alpha = 0$ and determine $C$.

Comment: @Integral, why is $I'(0)$ not well defined?

Comment: $I'(\alpha) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}-1}{\sqrt{\alpha}(\alpha -1)}$ by your own calculations. Now just make $\alpha = 0$ and see what happens.

Comment: @Integral, I see. Thank for pointing this. We can use the limit to overcome this.

Comment: It's a bit easier if we use $\log(\alpha +x^2)$ instead of $\log(1+\alpha x^2)$.  See [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901519/evaluate-an-improper-integral-involving-log/1901616#1901616).  ;-))

Answer (score 11):

We can also use contour integration to show that

$$I(a,b,\theta) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \left(a^{2}+2ax \cos \theta + x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}+b^{2}} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{b} \, \log \left(a^{2}+2ab \sin \theta +b^{2} \right), $$ where $a, b >0$ and $0 < \theta < \pi$.

Your integral is $\frac{1}{2} \, I\left(1,1,\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$.

---

Consider the complex function $$f(z) = \frac{\log \left(z+ae^{i \theta}\right)}{z^{2}+b^{2}},$$

which has a branch point in the lower half-plane at $z=-ae^{i \theta}$.

If we use the principal branch of the logarithm, then $f(z)$ is meromorphic in the upper half-plane.

So by integrating around a closed semicircular contour in the upper half-plane (and using the fact that $ \lim_{|z| \to \infty} z f(z) =0$ ), we get

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \left(x+ae^{i \theta} \right)}{x^{2}+b^{2}} \, dx = 2 \pi i \  \text{Res}[f(z),ib] = \frac{\pi}{b} \, \log \left( ib +ae^{i \theta} \right).$$

And equating the real parts on both sides of the equation, we get

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(a^{2}+2ax \cos \theta +x^2)}{x^{2}+b^{2}} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{b} \, \log \left(a^{2}+2ab \sin \theta +b^{2} \right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way by using contour integration and easy to understand:

Convention:

The branch of the logarithm is principal branch cut.

The argument is using under principal value.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}~dx = \\ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x^2+1)}{1+x^2}~dx = \\ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log((x+i)(x-i))}{1+x^2}~dx = \\\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(|x+i|) + Arg(x+i) + log(|x-i|)+ Arg(x-i) }{1+x^2}~dx = \\ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(|x+i|) + log(|x-i|)+ Arg(2x) }{1+x^2}~dx = \\$$$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(|x+i|) + log(|x-i|)}{1+x^2}~dx \tag{1}
$$

Doing contour integration with respect to function: $f(x) = log(x+i)/(x^2+1)$

Define contour:

$\Gamma_1:= x \text{ from } 0 \text{ to } \infty$

$\Gamma_2:= x \text{ from } \infty \text{ to } -\infty \text{ along the upper semicircle}$

$\Gamma_3:= x \text{ from } -\infty \text{ to } 0$

Easy to see: $\int_{\Gamma_2} |f(x)| \leq 2 \pi \max_{\Gamma_2} {\frac{|\log(x+i)|}{|1+x^2|}} \leq \frac{log(\sqrt{x^2+1})}{x^2+1}+\frac{\pi^2}{x^2+1}  = 0$

So $\int_{\Gamma_2} f(x)  = 0$

The residue for $f(x)$ at $x = i$ is $\frac{\log(2)+ \frac{\pi}{2}}{2i}$

By residue theorem: $\int_{\Gamma_1} f(x) + \int_{\Gamma_3} f(x) = 2\pi Res(f,i) = \pi \log(2) + \frac{\pi^2 i}{2} $

$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{log(x+i)}{(x^2+1)} + \int_{-\infty}^0  \frac{log(x+i)}{(x^2+1)} =  \pi \log(2) + \frac{\pi^2 i}{2} \implies\\\int_0^\infty  \frac{log|x+i|}{(x^2+1)} + \int_{-\infty}^0  \frac{log(|x+i|)+ \pi i}{(x^2+1)} =  \pi \log(2) + \frac{\pi^2 i}{2} \implies\\\int_0^\infty  \frac{log|x+i|}{(x^2+1)} + \int_{-\infty}^0  \frac{log(|x+i|)}{(x^2+1)}+ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{ \pi i}{(x^2+1)} =  \pi \log(2) + \frac{\pi^2 i}{2} \\$$

Recall: $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1} = arctan(x)+c$

$$ \implies \int_0^\infty  \frac{log|x+i|}{(x^2+1)} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{log(|x-i|)}{(x^2+1)}+  \frac{i\pi^2}{2} =  \pi \log(2) + \frac{i\pi^2}{2}\\\\\implies \int_0^\infty  \frac{log|x+i| +  log|x-i|}{(x^2+1)} =  \pi \log(2)  
$$

Substitute into $(1)$,$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(|x+i|) + log(|x-i|)}{1+x^2}~dx = \pi \log(2)$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x^{2} + 1} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}  =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x^{2} + 1} \over x^{2} + 1}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + \ic x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{{\Large 1\ +\ \ic x\ =\ s} \atop
{\Large x\ =\ \ic\pars{1 - s}}}{=}\,\,\,&
\Re\int_{1 - \infty\ic}^{1 + \infty\ic}{\ln\pars{s} \over
-\pars{1 - s}^{2} + 1}\,\pars{-\ic}\dd s
\\[5mm] & =\,
-\,\Im\int_{1 - \infty\ic}^{1 + \infty\ic}{\ln\pars{s} \over
s\pars{s - 2}}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Im\bracks{\color{red}{-}2\pi\ic\,{\ln\pars{2} \over 2}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm]= &\
\bbx{\pi\ln\pars{2}} \approx 2.1776 \\ &
\end{align}
In (\ref{1}), I "closed" the integration path with a infinite
radius semicircle on the "right" ( note the
$\ds{\color{red}{-}\mbox{sign}}$  because the contour integration
is clockwise ). The *magnitude of the contribution along the arc* $\ds{< \pi\root{\ln^{2}\pars{R} + \pi^{2}}/R}$ as
$\ds{R \to \infty}$ where $\ds{R}$ is the *semicircle radius*. $\ds{\ln}$ is the *logarithm principal branch*.