# Find integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \ dx$ (most likely substitution)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \ dx$$

I tried letting $x^2=\tan \theta$ but it didn't work. What should I do?

Please don't give full solution, just a hint and I will continue.

Comment: If $x = \tan\theta$ then $\dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = d\theta$ and $\ln(1+x^2) = 2\ln\sec\theta$, and as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/4$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: A pity the integrand isn't multiplied by $\,x\,$ ...The primitive of this function seems to be a nightmare, with polylogarithms of second order and stuff. It doesn't look nice.

Comment: I am afraid that this needs to be subjected to complex integration (contours, residues, Cauchy...) But then, for some this is utter joy!

Comment: Yeah, need polylogarithms to do $2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}lnsec\theta d\theta $

Comment: Do you really want to delete ALL your accounts or did you click the wrong button by mistake?

Answer (score 9):

By using the substitution $x=1/u$ judiciously, I can show that

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} = \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} + \int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2}$$

The first integral may be evaluated using Cauchy's theorem over a strange contour; [I evaluated it here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx/371327#371327), and it has value $\pi \log{2}$.  (I will reproduce here in the Appendix below.)

The second integral may be evaluated by using the Maclurin expansion of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$:

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \, \int_0^1 dx \, x^{2 k} \log{x} = -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2} = -G$$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).  Thus the integral sought is

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \log{2} - G \approx 0.172827$$

**APPENDIX**

To evaluate the first integral above, we consider the integral in the complex plane

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2}$$

where $C$ is some contour to be determined.  Our first instinct is to make $C$ a simple semicircle in the upper half plane.  The problem is that the branch point singularity at $z=i$ is extremely problematic, as it coincides with an ostensible pole.  Nonetheless, the corresponding integral over the real line is finite (and twice the originally specified integral), so there must be a way to treat this.

The way to go with branch points like this is to avoid them.  We thus have to draw $C$ so as to do that, and then use Cauchy's theorem to state that the above complex integral about $C$ is zero.  Such a contour $C$ is illustrated below.

[image: contour]

The contour integral is then taken along six different segments.  I will state without proof that the integral about the two outer arcs vanishes as the radius of those arcs $R \to \infty$.  We are then left with four integrals:

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} + \left [\int_{C_-}+\int_{C_+}+\int_{C_{\epsilon}} \right ] dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} = 0$$

$C_-$ is the segment to the right of the imaginary axis, down from the arc to the branch point, $C_+$ is the segment to the left of the imaginary axis, up from the branch point to the arc, and $C_{\epsilon}$ is the circle about the branch point of radius $\epsilon$.

It is crucial that we get the arguments of the log correct along each path.  I note that the segment $C_-$ is "below" the imaginary axis and I assign the phase of this segment to be $2 \pi$, while I assign the phase of the segment $C_+$ to be $0$.

For the segment $C_-$, set $z=i(1+y e^{i 2 \pi})$:

$$\int_{C_-} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} = i\int_R^{\epsilon} dy \frac{\log{[-y (2+y)]}+ i 2 \pi}{-y (2+y)} $$

For the segment $C_+$, set $z=i(1+y)$:

$$\int_{C_-} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} = i\int_{\epsilon}^R dy \frac{\log{[-y (2+y)]}}{-y (2+y)} $$

I note that the sum of the integrals along $C_-$ and $C_+$ is

$$-2 \pi \int_{\epsilon}^R \frac{dy}{y (2+y)} = -\pi \left [ \log{R} - \log{(2 + R)} - \log{\epsilon} + \log{(2 + \epsilon)}\right]$$

For the segment $C_{\epsilon}$, set $z=i (1+\epsilon e^{-i \phi})$.  The integral along this segment is

$$\begin{align}\int_{C_{\epsilon}} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} &= \epsilon \int_{-2 \pi}^0 d\phi e^{-i \phi} \frac{\log{\left [ -2 \epsilon e^{-i \phi} \right]}}{-2 \epsilon e^{-i \phi}}\end{align}$$

Here we use $\log{(-1)}=-i \pi$ and the above integral becomes

$$\begin{align}\int_{C_{\epsilon}} dz \frac{\log{(1+z^2)}}{1+z^2} &= -\frac12 (-i \pi)(2 \pi) - \frac12 \log{2} (2 \pi) - \frac12 \log{\epsilon} (2 \pi) -\frac12 (-i) \frac12 (0-4 \pi^2) \\ &= -\pi \log{2} - \pi \log{\epsilon} \end{align}$$

Adding the above integrals, we have

$$\begin{align}\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} -\pi \log{R} + \pi \log{(2 + R)} + \pi \log{\epsilon} - \pi \log{(2 + \epsilon)} -\pi \log{2} - \pi \log{\epsilon} &= 0\\ \implies \int_{-R}^R dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} -\pi \log{R} + \pi \log{(2 + R)} - \pi \log{(2 + \epsilon)} -\pi \log{2} &=0\end{align}$$

Now we take the limit as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ and we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} -2 \pi \log{2} = 0$$

Therefore

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} = \pi \log{2}$$

Comment: wow this looks amazing.

Comment: @AlexanderJones: thanks.  I hope you can appreciate the complex integration angle.

Comment: I wish I understand it haha. I have done all high school maths so what should I do next to work my way up to be able to understand and solve questions using the complex plane? What topics should I learn and in what order? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderJones: understand integration thoroughly, including some multivariate integrals used in line integrals and parametric functions, as well as continuity and differentiation.  Perhaps know what a Cauchy Principal Value is.  Then pick up a good introductory book like Churchill & Brown, although I am sure others may find a more recent and accessible reference.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So I should basically focus on learning more calculus for now :)

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x=\tan(\theta)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\sec(\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-\int_0^{\pi/4}\left[\log(1+e^{i2\theta})+\log(1+e^{-i2\theta})-2\log(2)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac\pi2\log(2)+2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\cos(2k\theta)}{k}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac\pi2\log(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\sin(k\pi/2)}{k^2}\\
&=\frac\pi2\log(2)-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\frac\pi2\log(2)-\mathrm{G}\\
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

---

**Integral Over $\mathbf{[0,\infty]}$**
The domain of the trigonometric integral above becomes $[0,\pi/2]$ and this translates to the sum
$$
\pi\log(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\sin(k\pi)}{k^2}=\pi\log(2)
$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Putting $x=\tan t, x=0\implies t=0$ and $x=1\implies t=\frac\pi4$  considering the principal values of $\arctan$

So, $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \ dx=\int_0^\frac\pi42\ln\sec tdt=-2\int_0^\frac\pi4\ln\cos tdt $$

$$I=\int_0^\frac\pi4\ln\cos tdt =\int_0^\frac\pi4\ln\cos\left(\frac\pi4+0- t\right)dt=\int_0^\frac\pi4\{\ln(\cos t+\sin t) -\ln \sqrt2\}dt$$ as $\cos\left(\frac\pi4+0- t\right)=\frac{\cos t+\sin t}{\sqrt2}$ and $\ln \frac ab=\ln a-\ln b$

$$2I=\int_0^\frac\pi4\{\ln(\cos t+\sin t)^2 -\ln 2\}dt=\int_0^\frac\pi4\ln(1+\sin2t)dt-\ln 2\int_0^\frac\pi4dt$$

Putting $u=2t$ in $$\int_0^\frac\pi4\ln(1+\sin2t)dt=\frac12\int_0^\frac\pi2\ln(1+\sin u)du$$

Now, use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x).

Comment: I see that my answer starts out like yours, but then I use the identity I found when writing [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/707628). (+1)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 +x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{x \equiv \tan\pars{\theta}}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 +x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}
> \,\dd x}
> =-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{{2\sin\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{\theta} \over 2}\,{\cos\pars{\theta} \over \sin\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
> =-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{2\theta}\cot\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cot\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> -\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=-G + {\pi \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}
> -\half\,\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\pars{1}
> \end{align}
>   where we used
>   [one of the Integral Representations of Catalan Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_constant) $\ds{G}$. Namely
>   $$
> G \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cot\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> $$

Let's evaluate the $\ds{\color{#00f}{\mbox{remaining integral}}}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}}
\,\dd\theta}
=\half\bracks{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2} - \theta}}\,\dd\theta}
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{2\theta}}\,\dd\theta
={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{\theta}}
\,\dd\theta
+{1 \over 4}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\half\,\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
=-\,{\pi \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}
+\half\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
\\[3mm]&\imp\quad
\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
=-\,{\pi \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}
\end{align}

> This result is replaced in $\pars{1}$:
>   $$\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 +x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}
> \,\dd x = \half\,\pi\ln\pars{2} - G}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

The substitution and complex variable methods used here are excellent, but this is the *perfect* problem for using Feynman's differentiation under the integral trick. Once we apply the substitution that Ron Gordon did, we look to evaluate the integral 
$$
I(t) = \int^{\infty}_0 \, \frac{\log{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Introduce a parameter $t$, such that
$$
I(t) = \int^{\infty}_0 \, \frac{\log{(1+tx^2)}}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Note that choosing where to introduce this new parameter into the function is a bit of an art! If we differentiate under the integral w.r.t. $t$, then
$$
I'(t) = \int^{\infty}_0 \, \frac{x^2}{(1+tx^2)(1+x^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Using partial fractions on this gives $$
I'(t) = \int^{\infty}_0 \, \frac{1}{(1-t)(1+tx^2)} -  \frac{1}{(1-t)(1+x^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
These are now the standard $\arctan$ integral, so
$$
I'(t) = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t}(1-t)}-\frac{\pi}{2(1-t)}.
$$
Integrating with respect to $t$ gives us 
$$
I(t) =\frac{\pi}{2}\log{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{t}}{1-\sqrt{t}}\right)} -\frac{\pi}{2}\log{(1-t)}+c.
$$
To determine the constant, we note that $I(0)=0$, so $c=0$. Combining the logarithms gives that 
$$
I(t) =\frac{\pi}{2}\log{(1+\sqrt{t})^2} = \pi \log{(1+\sqrt{t})}.
$$
This gives us a value for an entire *family* of integrals! Setting $t=1$ gives us the value of the original integral, 
$$
I(1) = \pi \log 2.
$$

*Edit - I tried to apply the technique to the original integral and it failed badly with $t$ in that position, but maybe there are other places to put it that make it work!*

Comment: I see from Ron Gordon's answer we can get the integral on $[0,1]$ from this integral.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am evaluating one of Ron's intermediate integrals slightly differently, I just like this technique and wanted to share :)

Comment: Ah, I was just noting that you can get the integral in the question from this integral using the method in Ron's answer. Just saying the same thing you are from a different point of view.

Comment: Ah yes, cool. Your answer is also nice!

Answer (score 0):

Integrate as follows

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} dx\\ 
=&\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{2x^2y}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2y^2)}dy\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi2 y-2\tan^{-1}y}{y^2-1}
\ \overset{y\to \frac{1-y}{1+y}}{dy}\\
= &\ \frac\pi2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+y}dy
 -\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}y}{y}dy=\frac\pi2\ln2-G
\end{align}