# Twin integrals, would like to know them precise.

Tags: calculus

I would like to know if there is a way how to calculate the following integrals:
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(1-\cos x) \mathrm dx
$$ as well as 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(1-\sin x) \mathrm dx
$$
Actually both integrals are equal to each other (which can be shown through that integral property $x→\pi/2-x$ substitution, sorry got no formal name for it). And so their difference results in zero. But is there a tricky way to evaluate one of them?
According to my TI it is around -2.920558 and so I suspect they are not divergent, as I first thought.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not very easy to integrate...

Comment: Symbolic calculators tell me that the answer is $-2 C-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log2$, where $C$ is Catalan's constant. That makes me suspect that the way to go is to expand $\log(1-u)$ into its power series, plug in $u=\cos x$, and try integrating term by term....

Comment: @GregMartin I wasn't really expecting a fine anti derivative. I was hoping, that since this is a definite integral, that these limits might be used to do the trick. After all, through the cofunction identity sine and cosines can be written in terms of one another. I was hoping that something like that could be used. The series may indeed be something else I could explore (tomorrow...)

Comment: Or perhaps use $1-\cos x=2\sin^2 x/2$ and $\sin z=z\prod_{k\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}}(1-\tfrac{z}{k\pi})$.

Comment: @GregMartin: I tried that, but you get a complicated series involving the Beta function. The approach I finally took was to write $1-\cos(x)=\dfrac{(1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})}{2}$ then use the series for $\log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1-\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\log(1-e^{ix})+\log(1-e^{-ix})-\log(2)\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac\pi2\log(2)-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac\pi2\log(2)-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(k\pi/2)}{k^2}\\
&=-\frac\pi2\log(2)-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=-\frac\pi2\log(2)-2\mathrm{G}
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It just doesn't come out nice unfortunately....Can't use Catalan's in my class :)

Comment: It's either use Catalan's constant or the series for it. I don't think you'll find anything simpler.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your method gives integrals of $\cos kx$ rather than the $\cos^kx$ straight from the power series. The latter wouldn't be insurmountable, but this is more direct, I agree. Well done!