# Integrating $\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{\arctan(x) - x}{x^2}\right)^2 \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

> **how to integrate** $$\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{\arctan(x) - x}{x^2}\right)^2 \,dx$$

**Attempt**
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{\arctan(x) - x}{x^2}\right)^2 \,dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^4} \cdot (\arctan(x) - x)^2 \,dx$$

Integrating by parts

$$I = -\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - 1\right)^2 + \frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x - \arctan(x)}{x(x^2 + 1)} \,dx$$

$$= -\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - 1\right)^2 + \frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \,dx - \frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x(x^2 + 1)} \,dx$$

Comment: The second term of the last line is easy. Third term, do partial fractions ...

Comment: Third integral is non-elementary, so IF integration by parts works AND if you can extract the original integral from it (and solve it as an equation) that is the only way it can be done. I used https://www.integral-calculator.com/ and it didn't "work"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the differentiation under the integral sign below
\begin{align}
I(a)=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(a x)}{x(x^2 + 1)}dx\\
I’(a)=& \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2x^2)}dx=\frac{\frac\pi4-a \arctan a}{1-a^2}
\end{align}
Then, the last integral is
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x(x^2 + 1)}dx\\
= &\int_0^1 I’(a)da
=\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi4-a \arctan a}{1-a^2}da \\
 =&\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi4- \arctan a}{1-a^2}da + \int_0^1\frac{ \arctan a}{1+a}da\\
 \overset{a\to \frac{1-a}{1+a}}=&\ \frac12\int_0^1\frac{ \arctan a}{a}da + \frac12\int_0^1\frac{ \frac\pi4}{1+a}da\\
=& \ \frac12G + \frac\pi8\ln2
\end{align}

Comment: $G$ is the Catalan constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ace

Answer (score 2):

In fact,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x(x^2 + 1)}dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}\arctan(x)\;d(\ln x-\frac12\ln(1+x^2))\\
&=&\arctan(x)(\ln x-\frac12\ln(1+x^2))\bigg|_0^1-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x-\frac12\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\;dx\\
&=&-\frac\pi8\ln2-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\;dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\;dx\\
&=&\frac12G + \frac\pi8\ln2.
\end{eqnarray}$$
Here
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\;dx=-G,\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\;dx=-G+\frac\pi2\ln2 $$
are used from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant and [Find integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \ dx$ (most likely substitution)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387631/find-integral-int-01-frac-ln1x21x2-dx-most-likely-substitution).