# Logarithmic Contour Integration

Tags: contour-integration

So, I'm having a really difficult time trying to evaluate the following integral via contour integration (please, no other methods):

$$\int_0^\infty{\frac{\log{(x^2+1)}}{1+x^2}} dx$$

Obviously, we're going to have branch cuts at z= +/- i which extend to infinity, and I'm having trouble coming up with a nice contour to evaluate this.  I already tried a double keyhole contour and split up the logarithm function, but this does not recover the real function I'm trying to evaluate.  Could anyone please provide some insight?

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx/371327#371327

Comment: Hmmm, I can follow that answer, but I'm having trouble showing that the R and epsilon integrals go to zero.  Most of the inequality arguements which I use to show that don't work very well....

Comment: You just have to draw the contour and then parametrize each piece and evaluate.  The epsilon integral, as you call it, does **not** go to zero, but rather cancels with another piece.  You should readily see how The integral over the large arc vanishes as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having some trouble showing that.  Usually, for contour integrals, I use a nice inequality argument to show that the integral's magnitude < or = to 0, but it doesn't work out well at all for these integrals.  Also, could you please elaborate on how you can assert that −πlog(R)+πlog(2+R)=0 as R approaches infinity? Normally, you can't conclude that infinity - infinity will lead to that result.

Comment: Well, I would argue the following: $$\log{(2+R)} = \log{R} + \log{\left(1+\frac{2}{R}\right)} \sim \log{R} + \frac{2}{R}$$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Ahhhh, that definitely makes sense and is a pretty clever explanation; thank you!  How do you personally see how the integral over the large arc vanishes?  That's what I'm really having trouble computing