# Typical Contour Inegral Proof

Tags: contour-integration

I'm trying to prove that the following contour integral approaches 0 as R -> $\infty$.  How exactly would we go about doing this?
$$
\int{\log\left(z^{2} + 1\right) \over 1 + z^{2}}\,{\rm d}z\quad
\mbox{over the curve}\quad  z=Re^{i\theta}\quad
\mbox{from}\quad \theta=0\ \mbox{to}\ \theta={\pi \over 2}.  
$$
Usually, I use inequality arguments to prove this, but they're not working very well ( the magnitude of the logarithm messes it up ).

How  are we showing that this integral approaches $0$ as $R \to \infty$ ?.

Comment: [An identical question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729727/logarithmic-contour-integration) has been asked recently, and closed off as [a duplicate of this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx) one.

Comment: The response did not adequately address this idea, which I am still curious about.  Please leave this open until an adequate response is provided.

Comment: Can we just pull the limit inside the integral?

Comment: @Lucian It's similar but it's not identical.