# Integrate $ \int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln^2(1+x)}{x^{3/2}} dx=8\pi \ln 2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate this integral.
$$
I=\int_0^\infty \frac{ \ln^2(1+x)}{x^{3/2}} dx=8\pi \ln 2
$$  Note $$
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}, \ |x| < 1.
$$
I was trying to do use this series expansion but wasn't sure how to go about it because of the square of the logarithm.  And also it seems than we then will have $I\propto \int_0^\infty x^{n-3/2}dx$ which will diverge. Thanks

Comment: I'd guess that the best way to proceed is to find an appropriate contour in the complex plane and integrate using residues.

Comment: @T.Bongers I am looking for a solution, thanks though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Integrating by parts,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{2}(1+x)}{x^{3/2}} \ dx &= - \frac{2 \ln^{2}(1+x)}{\sqrt{x}} \Bigg|^{\infty}_{0} + 4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{(1+x) \sqrt{x}} \ dx \\ &=4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{(1+x) \sqrt{x}} \ dx . \end{align} $$

Now let $x = u^{2}$.

Then

$$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{2}(1+x)}{x^{3/2}} \ dx &= 8 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+u^{2})}{1+u^{2}} \ du \\ &= 8 (\pi \ln 2) \tag{1} \\ &= 8 \pi \ln 2. \end{align}$$

$(1)$ [Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks, very clear.  No questions.  +10

Comment: Your editing makes this problem active and also makes me reminisce that this is the first problem I answered on Math SE. Thanks. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Since I just linked to this question, I thought I'd improve the formatting of my answer. Sometimes I wish you could make minor edits to an answer without bumping the question.

Answer (score 13):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x = 8\pi\ln\pars{2}:
     \ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{t \equiv {1 \over x + 1}\quad\iff\quad x = {1 \over t} - 1}$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x}=
> -2\int_{x = 0}^{x \to \infty}\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x}\,\dd\pars{x^{-1/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\bracks{2\ln\pars{1 + x}\,{1 \over 1 + x}}\,\dd x
> =4\int_{1}^{0}\pars{1 - t \over t}^{-1/2}\ln\pars{1 \over t}t
> \pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-4\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{t}t^{-1/2}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
> =-4\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}t^{\mu}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-4\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{{\rm B}\pars{\mu + 1,1/2}}{\mu}
> -4\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{}{\mu}
> \bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=-4\Gamma\pars{\half}\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\braces{%
> {\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}\,\bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1} - \Psi\pars{\mu + {3 \over 2}}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-4\Gamma^{2}\pars{\half}\,
> {\Psi\pars{1/2} - \Psi\pars{1} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}
> =-4\pars{\root{\pi}}^{2}\,{\bracks{-2\ln\pars{2} - \gamma} -\pars{-\gamma} \over 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large 8\pi\ln\pars{2}}
> \end{align}

Comment: You always have nice solutions with $\partial_\mu$ or $\partial_\nu$ with these special functions.  Very helpful to me....Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @Jeff They are very useful. Thanks.

Comment: You are an expert on special functions!

Comment: @xpaul Thanks. They are quite useful. For that reasons people call them 'specials'.

Answer (score 7):

Using Richard Feynman's favorite method, the method of differentiation under the integral sign.
$$
\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2(1+\alpha x)}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx\\
\frac{dI(\alpha)}{d\alpha}&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2x\ln(1+\alpha x)}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}(1+\alpha x)}dx\\
I'(\alpha)&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+\alpha x)}dx.
\end{align}
$$
Let $\,x=t^2\;\Rightarrow\;dx=2t\,dt$, then
$$
\begin{align}
I'(\alpha)&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha t^2)}{t(1+\alpha t^2)}\cdot2t\,dt\\
&=4\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha t^2)}{(1+\alpha t^2)}dt.
\end{align}
$$
To solve the integral part, again we use the method of differentiation under the integral sign.
$$
\begin{align}
I(\beta)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha\beta t^2)}{(1+\alpha t^2)}dt\\
\frac{dI(\beta)}{d\beta}&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\alpha t^2}{(1+\alpha\beta t^2)(1+\alpha t^2)}dt\\
I'(\beta)&=\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{1}{(\beta-1)(1+\alpha t^2)}-\frac{1}{(\beta-1)(1+\alpha\beta t^2)}\right]dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta-1}\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{1}{1+\alpha t^2}-\frac{1}{1+\alpha\beta t^2}\right]dt.
\end{align}
$$
Note that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+k y^2}dy=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
I'(\beta)&=\frac{1}{\beta-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\beta}-1}{\sqrt{\beta}(\beta-1)}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\beta}-1\right)}{\sqrt{\beta}(\beta-1)}\cdot\frac{\left(\sqrt{\beta}+1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\beta}+1\right)}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}\left(\sqrt{\beta}+1\right)}\right)\\
\frac{dI(\beta)}{d\beta}&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}+1}\right)\\
I(\beta)&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\int\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}+1}\right)d\beta\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\left(2\sqrt{\beta}-2\sqrt{\beta}+2\ln\left(\sqrt{\beta}+1\right)+\text{C}_1\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\left(2\ln\left(\sqrt{\beta}+1\right)+\text{C}_1\right).\\
\end{align}
$$
For $\beta=0$ implying $I_\beta(0)=0$, then $\text{C}_1=0$ and
$$
I_\beta(1)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha t^2)}{(1+\alpha t^2)}dt=\frac{\pi\ln 2}{\sqrt{\alpha}}.
$$
Now, plug in $I_\beta(1)$ to $I'(\alpha)$.
$$
\begin{align}
I'(\alpha)&=4\cdot\frac{\pi\ln 2}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\\
\frac{dI(\alpha)}{d\alpha}&=4\pi\ln 2\cdot\alpha^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
I(\alpha)&=4\pi\ln 2\int\alpha^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,d\alpha\\
&=(4\pi\ln 2)\left(2\alpha^{\frac{1}{2}}+\text{C}_2\right)
\end{align}
$$
For $\alpha=0$ implying $I_\alpha(0)=0$, then $\text{C}_2=0$. Thus
$$
I_\alpha(1)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx=\boxed{\color{blue}{\large8\pi\ln 2}}
$$

$$$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: clever solution.  Thanks for the new approach.

Comment: @Jeff You're welcome. Unfortunately, I failed to earn my first bounty.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to solve. Let
$$ I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha x)\ln(1+\beta x)}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx. $$
Note $I=I(1,1)$. It is easy to see that
$$ \frac{\partial^2I(\alpha,\beta)}{\partial\alpha\partial\beta}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{(1+\alpha x)(1+\beta x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{\alpha\sqrt{\beta}+\sqrt{\alpha}\beta}  $$
and hence
$$ \frac{\partial I(\alpha,1)}{\partial\alpha}=\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{\alpha\sqrt{\beta}+\sqrt{\alpha}\beta}d\beta=2\pi\frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}})}{\sqrt{\alpha}} $$
and 
$$ I(1,1)=\frac{\partial I(\alpha,1)}{\partial\alpha}=2\pi\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}})}{\sqrt{\alpha}}d\alpha=8\pi\ln 2. $$