# Solution of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+{x^2})}{1+{x^2}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How do I solve this?
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+{x^2})}{1+{x^2}}$$
I know the answer is $\pi\ln2$.

Comment: Posts which merely state a problem are discouraged on this site. Please improve your post by adding additional information. Where did the integral arise? Why is it of interest? What have you attempted already?

Comment: this integral was often solved on this forum

Comment: [There is search button on the top](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meh.

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1 + x^2}\ \text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1 + x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

Now set

$$x=\tan y$$

and you get:

$$-\frac{4}{2} \int^{\pi/2}_0 \ln(\cos y)\ \text{d}y = \pi \ln 2$$

**Other References**

[Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**But I prefer my method.**