# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x^{2}+1)}{x^{2}+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I tried to find $f(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x^{2}+a^{2})}{x^{2}+b^{2}}$. After differentiating I get : $f(a) = \frac{\pi \log(a+b)}{b} + C$. But it's not easy to find this constant. I represent constant as $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x^{2}+1)}{x^{2}+1} - \pi \log(2)$. Any hints ?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx. – Both found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog(x%5E%7B2%7D%2B1)%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: did you forget $dx$ on purpose?