# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Letting $x=\tan \theta$ yields $$
I:=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\sec ^{2} \theta\right) d \theta =-2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\cos \theta) d \theta
$$
By my [post](https://artisticmathematics.quora.com/Daily-Question-23-2-2021-Evaluate-the-Integral-math-displaystyle-int_-0-frac-pi-2-ln-sin-x-dx-math?ch=17&oid=42957043&share=6d1438ca&srid=CCOmo&target_type=post),
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=-2\left(-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2\right)=\pi \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

***My question:***
Is there any other simpler method to find the integral?

Comment: Simpler? Doubt it. Some contour approaches are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx) among others