# Why I am get complex values in this integral?

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I would like to get the following integral:

> $$\int -\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{(a^2+x^2)}dx \quad \text{or} \quad \int_{t}^{+\infty}-\frac{\log(a^2+x^2)}{(a^2+x^2)}dx$$

where $t>0$.

I used WolframAlpha to compute, and I got following expression:

[image]

I am just wondering why some complex value `i` appears? Any ideas of how to get the closed form of integral from t to +inf ? I guess I need to give more specification to wolframalpha to compute ?

Comment: An integral from $t$ to $\infty$ is no better than an indefinite integral when it comes to solvability. An integral from $0$ to $\infty$ may be a bit better.

Comment: my goal is to get the closed form of integration from t1 to t2 (real positive values). but I am just confused about the complex value i of the output... do you have any ideas which can guide me? thanks

Comment: @Jiadong: the three last terms are complex numbers when x,a are real do you know that the sum of complex numbers could be a real one?

Comment: Wolfram alpha is using the polylogarithmic integral for convenience. The complex numbers are just needed to make the polylogarithms applicable, but the whole expression will be entirely real.

Comment: @FShrike, ya, I know complex numbers can add up to get real numbers, but I haven't check this case. Maybe I will plug in some numbers to test.

Comment: If WolfromAlpha is right (I believe), last three terms definitely will add up to get a real number for any real x. Ya this might be a convenient way to represent..., but polylog is not easy to evaluate, but I accept this form if no better form out there.

Comment: Just a stupid question : what would you do by yourself (without WA) beside introducing in particular $x^2+a^2=(x+ia)(x-ia)$ before partial fraction decomposition ?

Comment: I meant to refer to what Claude is hinting. Wolfram Alpha is using complex numbers for convenience so that it can get an easier to integrate expression in terms of polylogs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For real $x$ and $a$ it is possible to rewrite the result using only real-valued functions. After copious use of the function relations
$$\arctan z=-\frac i2\log\frac{i-z}{i+z}$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{it})=\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi t}2+\frac{t^2}4+i\operatorname{Cl}_2(t)$$
where $\operatorname{Cl}_2$ is the [classical Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function), the simplified result is
$$\int_0^x\frac{\log(t^2+a^2)}{t^2+a^2}\,dt=\frac1a\left(2\log2a\arctan\frac xa-\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\pi-2\arctan\frac xa\right)\right)$$
The integral over $[0,\infty)$ is $\frac{\pi\log2a}a$; cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358386).

Comment: thanks:), definitely a more elegent form!